# Deployment and loading DLLs with IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Good morning,

I am working on a C# project. I have implemented an API in C# and uses also C++/CLI. I am developing on Visual Studio and my solution generates 5 DLLs. Those 5 DLLs are then integrated into a web application which uses ASP.net and deployed with IIS. In order to make the things working with IIS (load the DLLs at the execution), I need some DLLs into the folder of IIS server : C:\Program Files\IIS Express.
It bothers me a bit to copy some DLLs into the IIS Server folder. I would like to put the DLLs into a specific folder and indicates to IIS to load the DLLs at this place. I was thinking to use the “assembly resolver” but I did not succeed to have a solution which works. I would like to know if someone has an idea or a solution to make it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mixing managed and unmanaged code is not a great idea in IIS. The IIS application pools are different for this reason. Anyway, if you want to use your custom DLL you need to deploy them within your project distribution, but you need to call unmanaged code from managed.

Comment: You will have to show some code if the assemblies/libraries are loaded by code.

Comment: Well it is a bit complicated to share some code because it is a program that I work at my job. The solution contains managed Dlls, a wrapper Dll in C++/Cli. Unmanaged code is called from managed code. Concerning my problem I was thinking that IIS searches the Dlls to load in different locations and probably there is an order ; I try to put the path off my Dlls in the PATH variable but it does not work.

Comment: I suggest you open a case via : https://support.microsoft.com.